# How to correctly import SafeMath.sol into contract

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin

This has been a problem I've been dealing with for a while now. My temporary solution has been to create a SafeMath.sol file in my Contracts directory and directly import it from there. However, I've been looking for a 'clearer solution' to this... Old way seemed to be directly importing it from a GitHub link, as seen in some repos and other stack overflow posts like [such](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46299286/how-connect-library-to-smart-contract-from-external-resources)

However, the proper way do this seems to be installing the corresponding oz package (@openzeppelin/contracts-ethereum-package) and importing the file directly into the needed contract i.e.

`import "@openzeppelin/contracts-ethereum-package/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";`

However, using VSCode, I still get the error *Source "@openzeppelin/contracts-ethereum-package/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol" not found: File import callback not supported*

That said, how can I properly import SafeMath?

EDIT: I am using `pragma solidity ^0.6.0;`

Comment: I install lib `@openzeppelin/contracts` by npm and import the lib to my contract by `import "@openzeppelin/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";`

Comment: Implementation is ok. I think you have different issue here, check if the other `node_modules` are recognized by VSCode and debug that issue first.

Comment: In a recent update of Solidity the Integer type variables cannot overflow anymore. Read more about the following: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.3/080-breaking-changes.html

Comment: solc-js is dumb af I've been trying to figure out a way how to give the god damn path for 2 hours now

Answer (score 13):

I looked through the `node_modules` for the package `@openzeppelin/contracts`. Here is the current correct import path as of posting:

```js
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
```

Answer (score 6):

This is no longer needed with Solidity version 8

Comment: can you elaborate? I’m still running into this. I even tried to place file in same directory and still getting error. 

What’s the actual cause of this, if anyone knows?

Comment: More details: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/91367/is-the-safemath-library-obsolete-in-solidity-0-8-0

Answer (score 1):

path is different in v 3.0 [documentation](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/api/math)

I used this:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";
```

Instead of this:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be used in the following way:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v2.3.0/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";

contract contractForSafeMath {
    
    using SafeMath for uint;
    
    uint256 addResult;
    uint256 subResult;
    uint256 mulResult;
    uint256 divResult;
    uint256 modResult;
    
    uint public MAX_VALUE = 2**256 -1;
    //overflow
    uint256 overflowResult;
    
    function getResults(uint256 a, uint256 b) public{
         addResult = SafeMath.add(a,b);
         subResult = SafeMath.sub(a,b);
         mulResult = SafeMath.mul(a,b);
         divResult = SafeMath.div(a,b);
         modResult = SafeMath.mod(a,b);
         overflowResult = SafeMath.add(SafeMath.add ( (a**b), SafeMath.mul (SafeMath.mul (b, a), b)), (b** b));
    }
    
    function addResultVal(uint a, uint b) public view returns(uint256){
        return addResult;
    }
    
     function subResultVal() public view returns(uint256){
        return subResult;
    }
    
     function mulResultVal() public view returns(uint256){
        return mulResult;
    }
    
     function divResultVal() public view returns(uint256){
        return divResult;
    }
    
     function modResultVal() public view returns(uint256){
        return modResult;
    }
    
    function overflowResultVal() public view returns(uint256){
        return overflowResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow, here is a suggestion to improve the post : you can add a language identifier to highlight the code and make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the github page for any import you'll like to have for openzeppelin-contracts, "SafeMath" in this case, and copy the page url.
Ex:

```
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
```

Answer (score 0):

Import the library right after pragma solidity. Then include it right after the opening of your contract.

```
pragma solidity ^x.x.x;

import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";

contract TheNameOfYourContract {
    using SafeMath for uint;
    .
    .
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

creating a project from `npx hardhat` (2.8.3) selecting advanced project and then having a folder structure like this:

```
project
  |--contracts
       |--mycontract.sol
  |--node_modules
  |--{other files & folders}
```

The error is gone if I import libraries like this inside mycontract.sol:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

... other code
```

But this will not compile at least with hardhat. So it appears Solhint (.solhint.json) requires to know exactly the import paths but it ignores by default (.solhintignore) the node_modules folder. By removing node_modules from .solhintignore and restarting VS Code it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

No longer needed but import that works for pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
would be:
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/vendor/SafeMathChainlink.sol";

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).